# Unable to play file from a URL with ARI

Tags: asterisk

I have an application written in C# and I’m trying to play a media file from a URL to a channel using ARI and Asterisk 14 (for example: sound:http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02.wav), but the file is not played to the channel.

The asterisk wiki says that it is able to do this however I have followed the example and it does not work. I have the 'sound:helloworld' example working, but cannot get it to work through a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, channel should be in Statis app BEFORE you try do any action via ARI

Many people think they can do anything without dialplan, but no way.

https://docs.asterisk.org/Configuration/Interfaces/Asterisk-REST-Interface-ARI/Getting-Started-with-ARI/

Answer (score 0):

It should be working with Asterisk Version 15, It is working for me

```
$this->phpariObject->channels()->channel_playback($this->stasisChannelID, 'sound:http://10.41.10.101:8000/media/car-speech_20181024111752433.ogg', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'car');
```

Similar lib function will be in C#